# Cancel Previous request(if there are any) before making another while using debouncing in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch, abort

Sample react code what I am currently using...

I want to abort the request as soon as I make another request using debouncing.
Right now it cancels the very request it is making even for the first time.

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [mesg, setMesg] = useState(0);
  const [pin, setPin] = useState("");
  const abortCon = new AbortController();
  const signal = abortCon.signal;
  const debounce = (fn, timer) => {
    let time;
    return function () {
      let arg = arguments;
      let context = this;
      if (time) clearTimeout(time);
      time = setTimeout(() => {
        fn.apply(context, arg);
        time = null;
      }, timer);
    };
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (val) => {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    console.log(val);
    if (abortCon) abortCon.abort();
    fetch(url, { signal })
      .then((result) => {
        return result.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        // const result = await res.json();
        console.log(res.title);
        setPin(val);
        setMesg((prev) => prev + 1);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
  // const newHandler = debounce(onChangeHandler, 400);
  const newHandler = useCallback(debounce(onChangeHandler, 200), []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{mesg}</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="PIN code"
        value={pin}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPin(e.target.value);
          newHandler(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to abort the request as soon as I make another request using debouncing.
Right now it cancels the very request it is making even for the first time.

Comment: Your only creating a single controller. It looks like you need to make a new AbortController for each request. Use a useRef hook to first set it to null in your components route. Update all of your abortCon references to access the current property i.e. abortCon.current. Then after your if statement create the new Abort controller and set it to the ref abortCon.current = new AbortController().

Comment: @Jazz could you share a code snippet of what you are suggesting ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not making a new Abort Controller for each request.

So instead we save a ref to the AbortController using useRef(). Then create a new AbotrController and assign it to the ref at the start of each request.

Please see the updated code below:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [mesg, setMesg] = useState(0);
  const [pin, setPin] = useState("");
  const abortConRef = useRef();
  const debounce = (fn, timer) => {
    let time;
    return function () {
      let arg = arguments;
      let context = this;
      if (time) clearTimeout(time);
      time = setTimeout(() => {
        fn.apply(context, arg);
        time = null;
      }, timer);
    };
  };

  const onChangeHandler = (val) => {
    const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
    console.log(val);
    if (abortConRef.current) abortConRef.current.abort();
    abortConRef.current = new AbortController();
    fetch(url, { signal: abortConRef.current.signal })
      .then((result) => {
        return result.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        // const result = await res.json();
        console.log(res.title);
        // setPin(val);
        setMesg((prev) => prev + 1);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
  // const newHandler = debounce(onChangeHandler, 400);
  const newHandler = useCallback(debounce(onChangeHandler, 200), []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{mesg}</p>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="PIN code"
        value={pin}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPin(e.target.value);
          newHandler(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wright-f85hy?file=/src/App.js

Edit: I also commented out the setPin in the response callback. It was making the input buggy.